# File open with relative path fails

Tags: c, file-io

File open with fopen() fails when I provide a relative path. I am running this code on a windows machine with Visual Studio 2010.

```
const char* OUTPUT_FILE = "output/PERFORMANCE.txt";
FILE* f = fopen(OUTPUT_FILE, "w");
```

Is this way of specifying relative path incorrect? Should I be using "\" separator?

Specifying the absolute path using the same format works fine. (e.g "C:/output/PERFORMANCE.txt")

Comment: It should work. The question is relative to what? What's your working directory?

Comment: The directory the `.exe` is running from may not be the one you expect it to be. Then your relative path would be wrong.

Comment: When I specify the OUTPUT_FILE as "PERFORMANCE.txt" the new file is created in the same directory as the .exe. So I guess the working directory is the same as the .exe directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check what directory you are currently in. With Windows there are at least two ways:

1. [`_getcwd`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf98bd4y%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)
2. [`GetCurrentDirectory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364934%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Make sure you are in the directory you think you are, and make sure that the directory `output` exists in the directory, otherwise you'll need to create it. With Windows, there are at least two ways:

1. [`_mkdir`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2fkk4dzw%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)
2. [`CreateDirectory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363855%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

The file will fail to open (even for writing) if any intermediate directories are not present. The file may also fail to open if you do not have permissions to the target directory.

Answer (score 0):

Does the `output` subdirectory exist? Opening a file for write will create the file if it doesn't exist, but not the path to it.

Comment: Yes, the output directory exists